# Optimistic updates with react-navigation and relay

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, react-navigation, relay

I am building a `React-Native` app using `Graphql`, `Relay` and `React-Navigation`.

When I add a new record to a `FlatList` or `SectionedList`, I open a modal screen with react-navigation (navigate away from previous screen) and allow the user to enter the information and after that I fire off a mutation. I want to update the previous screen optimistically. i.e. I do not want to have to refresh the application to see the changes.

From my understanding I have two options:

1) I can pass the new data from the modal screen back to the screen through the react-navigation parameters and update state.

2) I can use Redux

I was curious if others had a better way of handling the update. Thanks

Comment: I Ended up using redux here…

Answer (score 0):

given that your data is in a connection, you can use the updaterConfig. Check the relay docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/mutations.html#range-add).

If you are not using a connection, it is a bit more tricky, but you can use the optimisticUpdater function to update the relay store. Relay docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/mutations.html#using-updater-and-optimisticupdater)